# How to run in full screen on start?

Tags: javascript, wimpy

http://www.wimpyplayer.com/

Was searching in the docs, but did not find how to run in full screen. Anyone maybe knows it?

Or where is the new version of skin machine for that player? When I enter to Google, I only find some [old](http://www.wimpyplayer.net/docs/rave/skin_machine.html) which is for Rave, I assume its for old version of the player. But I saw one online editor for new version, which I can't find.

I would then just remove panel of buttons, and set the size of the player with `setSize()` function.

Skin machine found, from browser history. Google does not find it even when it looks like I use exact keywords http://www.wimpyplayer.com/skinmachine/

Answer (score 0):

In the download ZIP there is a folder named "test" which includes this file:

"option-responsive-size-fullscreen.html"

... which you can use as a reference.

The trick is to use the "data-responsive" option to get wimpy to expand into the size of the page as defined in the CSS.

This is a cleaned-up version o the HTML needed to run in fullscreen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Wimpy Player - Fullscreen</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">


<!-- The following META tags are used to inform mobile-device browsers to present this page in full-screen mode.-->
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Wimpy Player" />


<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    /* Make page fill device window */
    html, body {
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:#484848;
    }
    /* For the Player Instance DIV */
    .full {
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
    }
</style>


<!-- Prevent entire page from "bouncing" -->
<script>document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){event.preventDefault();},false);</script>


<!-- Wimpy Engine -->
<!-- NOTE: Change WIMPY_INSTALLATION_FOLDER to target the wimpy.js file correctly. -->
<script src="WIMPY_INSTALLATION_FOLDER/wimpy.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<!-- Set the DIV's class to "full" and set the "responsive" option 
so the player automatically adjusts to fit snuggly within the view. 
The responsive option also causes the player to adjust itself when 
the orientation changes (e.g. from landscape to portrate) -->

<!-- NOTE: Change data-media to target media files or a playlist. -->
<div class="full" data-wimpyPlayer data-responsive data-media="song1.mp3|song2.mp3|song3.mp3"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
[This page on wimpyplayer.com](http://www.wimpyplayer.com/docs/fullscreen.html) that explains this as well.

Comment: the problem we noticed is that it did not show video on the couple of android phones, even from their site where are tutorials, just shows loader so we left this and stick to jwplayer which is more expensive but does its job without problems.

Comment: ant btw there still is full screen but with all buttons in that example. What I wanted is to see full video and without anything else. But I found the skin machine and edited the skin, removed buttons. Only  for some reason white space remained at the bottom of the video, like 100 pixels height, not sure why, but does not matter for now. THanks for trying to help